# Rename Unrecognized Pandas Columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to perform multiplication on columns in a dataframe, using:

```
totaldf[['Summer','LD/Offload']].multiply(totaldf['2018-04-01 00:00:00'], axis = 0)
```

However, I get a KeyError ONLY on the date column. When I print the column list:

```
Index([   'Summer',        'Pre-Winter',            'Winter',
          'LD/Offload', 2018-04-01 00:00:00, 2018-05-01 00:00:00...],
  dtype='object', name=0)
```

Since the date columns do not appear in quotations, I'm assuming that I can't identify them as I have in my operation.

I feel they need to be renamed, but I don't know how to access them.

EDIT: In the answers I found during my research, pandas.rename was the suggested solution. Since I couldn't figure out how to identify the columns, I couldn't use this method.

Comment: They are probably datetime objects, so you should also index them as a datetime object, not as a string.

Comment: Thanks Niels. For clarification, can someone please explain why this is getting downvoted? I researched beforehand, I tried making it "MCV", and I thought that I formatted it properly. I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Not by me, so I’m not sure why it gets downvoted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in my question, the answers I found suggested using the `pandas.rename` method, which I couldn't do without being able to access the columns.

The solution was to just put quotation marks around them in the list:

```
totaldf.columns = [..., '2018-04-01 00:00:00', ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the dataframe is using some type of datetime object for its columns. Might be more helpful if you show the type of the indexes that don't work.

If I were to bet, I'd bet that accessing that index using `pd.to_datetime('2018-04-01 00:00:00')` will solve your problem.